# How to enable MyBatis SQL logs in jboss?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, mybatis

I am not able to see the SQL generated by MyBatis in JBoss server logs , 
I have added below in jboss-log4j.xml to enable it , it did work before but for some reason have stopped working. Is there any other configuration we need to do to enable it.

```
 <logger name="org.apache.ibatis"> 
      <level value="debug"/> 
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> 
    </logger> 

    <logger name="java.sql"> 
      <level value="debug"/> 
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> 
    </logger> 

    <logger name="java.sql.Statement"> 
      <level value="debug"/> 
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> 
    </logger>


   <root>
      <!-- 
         Set the root logger priority via a system property. Note this is parsed by log4j,
         so the full JBoss system property format is not supported; e.g.
         setting a default via ${jboss.server.log.threshold:WARN} will not work.         
       -->
      <priority value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>
```

Comment: How do I add answer to this ? I had to change   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `jboss-log4j.xml` threshold value in CONSOLE appender ,

After changing INFO to DEBUG it worked without any issues

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
```

to

```
 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
```